# Task List or Tasks List?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I wonder, which is correct to use as a title for list (on a website, f.e.)

- Task List
- Tasks List
- List of Tasks

and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to a list of things to do (*i.e* tasks), then your first choice should be **Task List**.

Although less commonly used, **List of Tasks** is also correct.